# Allow TeamCity to run multiple builds at once

Tags: java, teamcity

I have a TeamCity config which runs a build on my Github repo, on a push to any branch. I have two build agents, and the `Limit the number of simultaneously running builds` setting set to `0 (unlimited)`.

When someone pushes to the repo, the build triggers and queues correctly. But when two branches are pushed more or less at the same time, while both builds are queued, only one will run at a time, even if an agent is available to run the second one. The setting makes me think it should be able to run both at once. The build displays both agents in the `Compatible Agents` tab. If two different configs are queued at the same time, both agents will be used.

How do I configure TeamCity to use both agents for the one build config?

Comment: Do you have any "Shared Resources" (locks, speicifcally) configured for these builds?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin No, not for this build.

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with a plugin: https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node/issues/136